# Tempus Dominus allowMultiDate incorrectly places current date into input field

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I am trying to implement a multidate input with Tempus Dominus. I set the picker to display a month or so in advance. I have useCurrent set to false.

When I select a date from the picker a month or so in advance the current date is inserted also and the picker pane jumps back to current dates month pane.

I am wondering if there is a work around or do I have to modify the code.

Please see the jsfiddle

```
$(function() {

   var minDate = moment().add(2, 'months').startOf('month');
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        allowMultidate: true,
        useCurrent: false,
        viewDate: minDate,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        multidateSeparator: ','
     });
 });
```

[Tempus Dominus Incorrectly Inserted Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvn01.png)

[JSFiddle Tempus Dominus](https://jsfiddle.net/jmcd73/bdxss6m8/1741/)